# Import component not working

Tags: react-native

Custom Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import { Content } from 'native-base'

export default class Login extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Content>
        <Text>This is stateless Component</Text>
      </Content>
    )
  }
}
```

index.ios.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Title, Content } from 'native-base'
import Login from './src/components/Login'

export default class MyApp extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Title>Login</Title>
        </Header>
        <Login />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp)
```

Only showing header in the running App. Expected `This is stateless Component` is not there. Can any one look into this please?

Comment: Try putting <content> inside a wrapper div

Comment: @morne Tried. No Luck!

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No error.  It's build and run successfully. Custom component data is not there....

Comment: Try reduce the scope of the problem. Say, remove Content component and just render Text component instead. If it does render, than something is wrong with native-base library

Comment: Ya i tried that way also. I think may be something missing that i can't see with my eyes !!

Comment: Did the text within the Text component renders? That is without using the Content component from native-base.

Comment: Yes that way i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*Content*](https://docs.nativebase.io/COMPONENTS.html#Content_Anatomy) component of the *native-base* only in the *container* component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Content } from 'native-base'

export default class Login extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <Container>
          <Content>
            <Text>This is stateless Component</Text>
          </Content>
        </Container>
     )
   }
}
```